# EF6 doesn't generate Entity Data Model as expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two entities. Event and User. I want to save the creator (= user) of the event as contact in my Event entity. Additionally i want to have several guides (= user as well) associated with my event.

This is (part of) my code:

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string LoginName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
}

 public class Event
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    public User ContactName { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }    // These are the guides
    public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public EventType Type { get; set; }
}
```

I'm expecting EF6 (6.1.3) to create 1:n and n:m relationships between User and Event. What it does instead can be seen in the screenshot below:

[image: This is what EF6 generates from my model]

There is one 1:n relation - as expected. But instead of one n:m relation there is one 1:n and one n:1 relationship. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many to many link, You have to write it in the function :

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasMany<Event>(s => s.Events)
                .WithMany(c => c.Users)
                .Map(cs =>
                        {
                            cs.MapLeftKey("UserRefId");
                            cs.MapRightKey("EventRefId");
                            cs.ToTable("UserEvent");
                        });

}
```

It's imply a new table between the two others

You can follow this [guide](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Works flawlessly. Thank you. But do I really HAVE TO write it like that? Because the many to many relation works when i omit the property "ContactName". Why do I have to tell EF how to resolve the relation in this specific case?

Comment: No, you are right, I think it should work without. Have you set a ForeignKey like Developper suggest you ? I think the modeling engine is a little bit lost when there are multiple reference on same entity. To my experience, sometimes we have to add a little fluent code to achieve what we want in code first alas...

Comment: Yes I did. Still no luck. Going to leave it like you suggested. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

There isnt a foreign key relation mapped in Event class:

```
public class Event
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }

    public int ContactId {get ; set;}
    [ForeignKey("ContactId")]
    public virtual User Contact { get; set; } 

    public virtual ICollection<Room> Rooms { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }    // These are the guides
    public virtual ICollection<Equipment> Equipments { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public EventType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but this doesn't work for me. The result is the same